# how to restore a logical partition to its original ext4 format

Tags: partition, data-recovery, ext4, restore

This question is following [Unable to mount /home/ partition after reinstalling grub after reinstalling windows 7](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50774/unable-to-mount-home-partition-after-reinstalling-grub-after-reinstalling-wind) where the diagnostic was that installing windows 7 deleted my `/home` partition, lovingly called `/dev/sda3`.

Since almost nothing have been done with this computer since the incident, we can expect that the content of the partition is still intact and that it is only unusable for the moment.

The mission is to try to rescue the files that were inside this partition by restoring it to its original ext4 format.

Does anyone know how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right off the bat make a dd disk image of the drive, and work with that instead of the drive itself. That lets you experiment.

```
dd if=/dev/sda3 bs=1M > sda3.img
```

Beyond that I'm not sure. I'd hit google. Might look at it later.

edit; http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk looks promising.

Comment: Testdisk is a good option.

Comment: I prefer using `of=sda3.img`, because using `>` is provided by the shell. Usually both work fine, but only the `of`-method is always guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to restore my partition by following the TestDisk tutorial: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step